# How can I categorize numbers that inside a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that has 5000 lines. It's format is like that:

```
1,3,4,1,2,3,5,build
2,6,4,6,7,3,4,demolish
3,6,10,2,3,1,3,demolish
4,4,1,2,3,4,5,demolish
5,1,1,1,1,6,8,build
```

I want to make different lists for example:
**for second column:**

```
second_build=[3,1]
second_demolish=[6,6,4]
```

I've tried something like that:

```
with open('cons.data') as file:
    second_build=[line.split(',')[1] for line in file if line.split(',')[7]=='build']
```

But It did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply first make the `readlines` a variable, then in the list comprehension simply add a `rstrip` then will work, because the values (except the last) all have `'\n'` at the end, so strip them out, and make them integers:

```
with open('cons.data') as file:
    f=file.readlines()
    second_build=[int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in f if line.rstrip().split(',')[-1]=='build']
    second_demolish=[int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in f if line.rstrip().split(',')[-1]=='demolish']
```

And now:

```
print(second_build)
print(second_demolish)
```

Is:

```
[3, 1]
[6, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get values for each column/action as follows:

```
lines = """1,3,4,1,2,3,5,build
2,6,4,6,7,3,4,demolish
3,6,10,2,3,1,3,demolish
4,4,1,2,3,4,5,demolish
5,1,1,1,1,6,8,build""".split(
    "\n"
)

build_cols = [list() for _ in range(7)]
demolish_cols = [list() for _ in range(7)]
data = {"build": build_cols, "demolish": demolish_cols}

for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(",")
    for bc, tok in zip(data[tokens[-1]], tokens):
        bc.append(tok)

# to access second column build values:
print(build_cols[1])
# ['3', '1']
```

For example, `build_cols` stores a list of lists, each entry represents a column. For each build line, you append items from an appropriate column to the corresponding position in the `build_cols`.